# What is quad 8:1 MUX?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, multiplexer, logic-level, rtl

In my assignment i'm asked to show a block diagram for quad 8:1 Multiplexer. But i have no idea what the word quad means in this question. Can someone help me?

Comment: quad - 4 as in quadrilateral (4 sided) quad bike (4 wheels) etc.

Comment: @JImDearden So what does it mean here? A MUX with 4 bit inputs?

Comment: it means 4 muxes (in one package)

Comment: just google 8:1 Multiplexer and then you have 4 of those

Comment: A MUX is a multiplexer. An 8:1 multiplexer can select from 8 inputs. Quad means 4 elements in one package, so in this case, 4 multiplexers.

Answer (score 0):

"Quad" means "four". Compare 7400, the "Quad 2-input NAND", for instance:

[image: 7400 Quad 2 Input NAND diagram]

In the context of your part name, it simply means that a single package contains four 8:1 muxes.